# What is the google App actions review process time length?

Tags: android, app-actions, google-assistant

How long does google take to review app actions?
Is there anywhere in the dev console to see the review status? As there it for app review status.
Many thanks

Just to clarify...
I am not talking about the app itself. I am talking about APP ACTIONS.
It says here `After you upload your app to the Play Console, we'll contact you at the email in Play Console with more information regarding the status of your App Actions review.`
https://developers.google.com/assistant/app/get-started

Comment: I guess you are talking about build review on play console upload. If it's for the first time It takes a maximum of 24 hours. I uploaded a test build a few weeks ago on internal testing. For the first time, it took 20 hours

Comment: @VinitBhavsar please see my updated question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Approximately it takes one to two weeks for App Actions reviews. Although, you might get an answer earlier.